# Get a set of files from multiple servers in a directory structure, manipulate the files, and put them all in one file

Tags: linux, bash, etcpasswd

I cannot figure this out because my bash skills aren't that strong and I haven't been able to find an existing script to do this after much googling.

I use `pslurp` to grab the `/etc/passwd` file from multiple servers. That puts the `/etc/passwd` in a directory structure `/servername/password`

```
pslurp -h serverlist -L localdir /etc/passwd password
```

Then I need to take each of those password files that I just grabbed and adjust them to only show the usernames of users with the ability to login interactively. I do that by excluding any users with a shell of `/sbin/nologin` for each of the `/servername/password` files and output to a new file

```
grep -v "/sbin/nologin$" password | cut -d: -f1 > /servername/newfile
```

Once I've got that, I'll need to get all of the `/servername/newfile` contents into 1 combined file with a format of

**servername**

list contents of `/servername/newfile` under each servername

**servername**

list contents of `/servername/newfile` under each servername

and so on ...

I've been working on this for a couple of days but just can't get it to happen. Please help!

Comment: Where do you get your list of servers from? Put them in an array, use `ssh` + `awk` to build the new combined file on the fly without any of the `/servername/password` temp files.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have set up passwordless login by `ssh` to the servers to collect `/etc/passwd` from (or want to just enter the password for each when prompted), you don't need `pslurp` or any other canned utility, all you need is `ssh` and `awk`. For example to retrieve and combine all `/etc/passwd` files from a list of servers removing all entries that contain `nologin` or `false` (for `/bin/false`) and writing them out in a format of:

```
server1
list of login users

server2
list of login users

...
```

All you need is a simple array containing the server names and the following, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=(server1 server2 server3)   # list of servers to get /etc/passwd from

{ # brace enclosed operation
for i in "${servers[@]}"; do        # loop over each server
    # ssh in and on success outut server name and contents without nologin or false
    ssh "$i" "printf '\n%s\n' '$i'; awk '/nologin/||/false/{next}1' /etc/passwd"
done
} > newfile                         # redirect output to new file
```

That will create `newfile` with the format and contents you describe without using any temporary files locally.

If you want the flexibility to redirect the output to `stdout` or any file of your choosing, just remove the brace-enclosed grouping an redirection within the script and redirect the output (or let it print to `stdout`) when you run the script.

There are endless ways to approach this, but this is one that is relatively straight-forward. For instance, if you do not have bash on the servers, but are limited to POSIX shell, you can use a simple list of servers instead of an array and the remainder would work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Given some fake password files like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── svrA
│   └── passwd
├── svrB
│   └── passwd
└── svrC
    └── passwd
```

One awk command is sufficient:

```sh
awk -F: '
    FNR==1 {
        split(FILENAME, f, "/")
        printf "\n%s\n\n", f[1]
    }
    $NF !~ /\/(nologin|false)$/
' */*
```

outputs this, that you can redirect into a file

```
svrA

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
user1:x:1000:1000:Parallels:/home/user1:/bin/bash

svrB

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
user2:x:1000:1000:user2:/home/user2:/bin/bash

svrC

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
user3:x:1000:1000:user3:/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

Do you want to ignore `/bin/false` and `/usr/bin/false` as login shells as well?